# How to extract the day number from a date string with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a string that changes to any given date like so

```
Thursday, November 1, 2018
```

or

```
Wednesday, December 12, 2018
```

I need to extract the day number...

```
1
```

or

```
12
```

What regex incantation allows this? (I suck at regex and I've spent hours trying to figure this out)

(Or Is there a ruby method that can do this as well?)

Comment: The best way here would probably be to parse your text dates into a Ruby date type using some appropriate function, then ask for day of the month.  Pure regex is probably a backup method.

Comment: If it has to be regex `'(\d+)(?:(?=,))'` should get you your desired output.

Comment: yep @moys that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If the date will be default as always that way.

You can slice it

```
q = "Wednesday, December 12, 2018"
q[-8..-7].strip

x = "Thursday, November 1, 2018"
x[-8..-7].strip
```